# Showing data in webpage from Matlab

Tags: matlab, html

I am getting data in COM port, processing it and showing it in Matlab (These are some readings from Sensors). Now the data I am showing in Matlab - I want to show same data in a webpage. I have been searching for some clue to start with this problem matter, but failed to find any. Please give me some suggestions/tips on how should I start. It will update the data real-time or at least in a time interval, so that the user would know about any changes sooner by checking the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean show as in `plot`?
You can just save the plots as images and move those to your webserver (which ideally runs on the same machine; if it's a remote server, take a look at Matlab's `ftp` class).
Then have a website which displays the image and either reloads fast or uses something like `AJAX` or `jQuery` to reload only the picture. Or include an "Update" button.

But that's an entirely different topic.
You might want to look into `HTML`, `JavaScript` and specifically `AJAX` for the webpage.

For Matlab, see `saveas` and, as stated above, possibly `ftp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I would like to show whatever my matlab is processing (not necessarily the data will be suitable for plotting). So it would be preferable if I could fetch the data from Matlab and show it somehow in my webpage. But thanks for your answer, that would help me to start off with.

Comment: You can save the variables in pretty much any format you choose to emulate and save it on your server. Depending on the data structure, you can then read and format it. You might need `php` to handle the data on the web server. Or you could create a table like figure in Matlab and save that as an image. But that's a giant project. An answer on here won't be able to do much more than point you towards the tools you could use.